# Angular: get data from formArray and send it to api

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I have a form to create quiz, and I want to get the data from it and save it into an object that object contains 2 properties first the number-of-questions and an array of objects which holds the questios,  **the problem is** when I'm trying to save the questions each question override all the previous ones! **[Last index overrides all the precious]**

this is the form which is a formarray each index holds a question and I have button add new question

```
this.questionsForm = new FormGroup({
      'theWholeForm':new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          "question": new FormControl(null) ,
          "qusetionPoints": new FormControl(null) ,
          "trueOrFalseAnswer":new FormControl(null),
          "mcqAnswer":new FormArray([new FormControl(null),new FormControl(null),new FormControl(null),new FormControl(null)]),
          "fillInTheBlankAnswer":new FormArray([new FormControl(null),new FormControl(null)]),
          "essayAnswer":new FormControl(null),
          "questionType":new FormControl({ name: "True or False"}) 
        })
      ]),
    });


getTheWholeForm(){
    return (this.questionsForm.get('theWholeForm') as FormArray).controls;
  }
```

I have created an interface called Quiz Questions to save these values

```
export interface QuizQuestions{
    numberOfQuestions:number;
    questions:{
        questionTitle:string,
        qusetionPoints:number,
        questionType:string,
        trueOrFalseAnswer?:string
        mcqAnswer?:[]
        fillInTheBlankPossibleAnswers?:[]
        essayAnswers?:string
    }[]
}
```

then I created an object :

```
quizQuestions:QuizQuestions = { numberOfQuestions:0,questions:[{
    questionTitle:'',qusetionPoints:0,
    questionType:'',
    trueOrFalseAnswer:'notSelected',
    mcqAnswer:[],
    fillInTheBlankPossibleAnswers:[],
    essayAnswers:'notSelected'
  }] }
```

this is the function where I'm saving the data:

```
clickme(){
        //I was getting an error here says that it can't read properties of undefined in any index more than 0, So I set all the indexes equal to index 0 
        
       this.quizQuestions.questions.length = this.getTheWholeForm().length;
        
        for(let i =1;i<this.getTheWholeForm().length;i++){
          this.quizQuestions.questions[i]= this.quizQuestions.questions[0];
        }
        
        for(let i =0;i<this.getTheWholeForm().length;i++){
          this.quizQuestions.questions[i].questionTitle = this.getTheWholeForm()[i].get('question')!.value;
          this.quizQuestions.questions[i].qusetionPoints = this.getTheWholeForm()[i].get('qusetionPoints')!.value;
          this.quizQuestions.questions[i].questionType = this.getTheWholeForm()[i].get('questionType')!.value;
          this.quizQuestions.questions[i].trueOrFalseAnswer =  this.getTheWholeForm()[i].get('trueOrFalseAnswer')!.value;
          this.quizQuestions.questions[i].mcqAnswer = this.getTheWholeForm()[i].get('mcqAnswer')!.value
          this.quizQuestions.questions[i].fillInTheBlankPossibleAnswers =  this.getTheWholeForm()[i].get('fillInTheBlankAnswer')!.value;
          this.quizQuestions.questions[i].essayAnswers =  this.getTheWholeForm()[i].get('essayAnswer')!.value;
        }
      }
```

**The Problem as I said that all indices are all override by the values of the last index entered**

Comment: you can get the value of formarray using just thewholeform.value and then just map it to whatever you want to save

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but could you please provide an example of how to do it correctly cause I'm stuck into it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ZiadMohamed Please make an example on https://stackblitz.com/